# Angular: i can´t iterate in array inside array in a model

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a table in which I load data from an array that comes to me through an API. So far so good. Some of them are array within array but in the view I´ve accessed these elements. The problem comes when I want to transfer this data to a modal. If the data comes in an array within an array in the modal it doesn´t show them to me in {{pais.currencie.name}}: core.mjs:6402 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

How should I do it?

**Array**
[array data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EhPS.png)

**html view**

```
<tr *ngFor="let pais of paises">
          <td>{{ pais.region }}</td>
          <td> {{ pais.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ pais.capital }}</td>
        
          <td *ngFor="let currencie of pais.currencies">{{ currencie.name }}</td> 
</tr>
```

**html model**

```
<ul class="list-group text-dark mb-3">
                   <li class="list-group-item active">{{pais.name}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">{{pais.capital}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">{{pais.currencie.name}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Población: {{pais.population}}</li>
                 </ul>
```

**modal ts**

```
@Input() pais: Paises | any;
```

**view ts**

```
 paises: Paises[] = [];
  paisSeleccionado: Paises | any;

 openModal(pais: Paises){
    this.paisSeleccionado = pais;
    this.modalService.openModal();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `currency` property in your model but `currencies`.
And from `currencies`, you can't access `name` directly as `currencies` is an array.

Comment: So, how can I access to currencies name in the model? I can in the view but not in the model.

Comment: that's because currencies is an array and you are accessing by iterating over the array firstly. As it's an array, you can't do currencies.name. You must either iterate over it or target a given currencies, for example currencies[0].name

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about how you're passing data between components, it's hard to diagnose where you issue is coming from. Update your post with a more complete view and we should be able to help.

Comment: Hi, I´ve upload more details. Thanks

Comment: is your modal inside the table row? if it's not located within the html tags of the table row, then you can't use "pais" variable to access the values in the array.